# Bokeh Server loading a Static CSS Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, bokeh

I've created a project and I'm attempting to load a static CSS for the styling of the webpage. However No matter what I do it does not appear to load. It gives me an internal 500 error. The docs are rather limiting on explaining how it works and how to setup it up. They just show a screeshot of the folder structure.

I tried using this but no luck, and I'm not entirely sure if i even need it, the docs don't really say.

```
{% include './static/css/custom.css'%}
```

Here is my setup.

```
myapp
   +---main.py
   +---static
   |    +---css
   |    |    +---special.css
   |
   |---templates
   |    +---index.html
   |
   +---theme.yaml
```

However here is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  {% block head %}
  <head>
    {% block inner_head %}
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>{% block title %}{{ title | e if title else "Bokeh Plot" }}{% endblock %}</title>
      {% block preamble %}{% endblock %}
      {% block resources %}
        {% block js_resources %}
          {{ bokeh_css | indent(8) if bokeh_css }}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block css_resources %}
          {{ bokeh_js | indent(8) if bokeh_js }}
        {% endblock %}
      {% endblock %}
      {% block postamble %}{% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  {% endblock %}
  {% block body %}
  <body>
    <h1>MY MAP</h1>
    {% block inner_body %}
      {% block contents %}
        {% for doc in docs %}
          {{ embed(doc) if doc.elementid }}
          {% for root in doc.roots %}
            {{ embed(root) | indent(10) }}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endblock %}
      {{ plot_div | indent(8) }}
      {{ plot_script | indent(8) }}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
  {% endblock %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full path from the application directory. So if the application folder is called myapp, the include statement should be:

```
{% include 'myapp/static/css/custom.css'%}
```

Comment: im having issues though where it wont load the latest css. it still references the old one.

Comment: Is it now registering the css file? Also the changes wont appear until you restart the server. Failing that try a hard reload in your browser

Comment: alright thank you. I was trying to find where on my computer the server saves the files. Is there a way to easily reload the html page after the server is launched, or do i have to restart the server each time i edit the html?

Comment: Yes you would need to restart each time unfortunately.